# Representations of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ as super vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, superalgebra

I heard someone say that representations of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ "are" super vector spaces. As far as I understand, super vector spaces are $\mathbb{Z}/2$-*graded* vector spaces, so my question is whether there is a canonical way of obtaining a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded vector space from a representation of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my best guess: let's write $\Bbb Z_2 = \{0,1\}$.  A representation of $\Bbb Z_2$ consists of any assignment $\rho(1) = A:V \to V$ for which $A^2 = I$.  Given such a linear transformation $A$, we have
$$
V = \ker (A - I) \oplus \ker(A + I)
$$
We would then take $V_0 = \ker(A - I)$ and $V_1 = \ker(A + I)$, in the notation of the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space).

Conversely, for any decomposition $V = V_0 \oplus V_1$, we could define a map $A$ by extending the definition
$$
Av = \begin{cases}
v & v \in V_0\\
-v & v \in V_1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: In a representation of a group, every element acts as an automorphism, so its kernel is zero...

Comment: Sorry, had projections on the brain

Comment: This seems to make sense, thanks. One can by the way describe this grading (at least for fields of characteristic $\neq 2$) also by decomposing the representation as $V \cong k_t^n \oplus k_s^m$, where $k_t$ is the trivial 1-dimensional representation and $k_s$ is the 1-dimensional sign representation, and declaring the "$k_t$ part" to be the even part and the "$k_s$ part" to be the odd part.